# Share Instagram post on my app automatically

Tags: android, instagram, instagram-api

I want whenever user post on Instagram it will automatically be posted on my app. 
I have already created an app which is similar to photo sharing. I know there is Instagram API using this API I can get user posts but there is two problem in using API.

1- To use API I need to get `access_token` Getting **access_token** is not issue but it expires after some time. I want to refresh access_token without user interaction. Is it possible? A user only allows the first time and after that, it will automatically refresh when it expires.

2- How can I know user posted something new or not. How can I detect any event or callback whenever a user posts something on Instagram. Because I think it is not possible with API. How I detect when a user posts something on Instagram.